Condition for series expansion of a parametric integral
Suppose you have a function $h:(0,1)\times (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ and a parametric integral of the form:
$$
I(x)=\int_x^1 h(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
Question: What would be the conditions on $h$ so that the series expansion of the integral around $x=1$ up to a certain order $n$ is obtained by computing the series expansion of $h(x,y)$ around $y=1$, integrating them term by term (up to a possible rational change of variable to go from $\int_x^1 \to \int_0^1$) and then computing the series expansion around $x=1$ of the final result?
More precisely, if we make the change of variable of the form $y\to \frac{x}{1+(x-1)y}$ in the integral (the bounds change $\int_x^1 \to \int_0^1$) and define the new integrand accordingly
$$
\bar{h}(x,y):= \frac{(1-x) x}{\left[(x-1) y+1\right]^2}h\left(x,\frac{x}{(x-1) y+1}\right),
$$
if we denote the series expansion (in general Laurent or Puiseux) of $\bar{h}$ with respect to y around $y=1$ as
$$
\bar{h}(x,y)\underset{y\to 1}{=}\sum_{k=p}^n \beta_k(x)(1-y)^{k+\alpha} + \mathcal{O}\left((1-y)^{n+\alpha+1}\right),\quad p\in \mathbb{Z},\ 0<\alpha<1,\ p+\alpha > -1,
$$
and then if we define the function
$$
\bar{H}(x)=\sum_{k=p}^n\beta_k(x) \int_0^1 (1-y)^{k+\alpha}\, \mathrm{d}y=\sum_{k=p}^n \frac{\beta_k(x)}{\alpha+k+1}
$$
with the series expansion around $x=1$ being
$$
\bar{H}(x)\underset{x\to 1}{=}\sum_{k=q}^n \gamma_k (1-x)^{k+\bar{\alpha}+1}+\mathcal{O}\left((1-x)^{n+\bar{\alpha}+1}\right),\quad q\in \mathbb{Z},\ 0<\bar{\alpha}<1,
$$
the question is: under which conditions on $h$ can we say that the series expansion of $I(x)$ around $x=1$ is that of $\bar{H}$?
If we go into more details, we also have the following knowledge:

The function $h$ actually has a simpler representation, i.e. there exist two functions $f$ and $g$ such that
$$
h(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}f(y)g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right),
$$
i.e. the integral is a Mellin convolution of two functions $f$ and $g$, but in principle for our purpose this piece of information doesn't simplify the problem.
The above mentioned functions $f$ and $g$ are rational or algebraic functions, for example of the form $\frac{1}{x}$, $\frac{1}{2-x}$, $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x}}$, etc. What is important is that the functions might not be finite at $x=1$, they could only be integrable. This makes the problem a bit complicated because a function like $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x}}$ does admit only a one-sided Puiseux series expansion around $x=1$, and because it's being notoriously divergent there are no real bounds on the remainder term.

Given this is a rather general problem and it involves at the same time integrals with a parameter, general series expansion and also is somehow in the nasty case where the point around which we want to expand involves divergent functions, it doesn't seem like  Taylor theorem, Fubini theorems/dominated convergence theorems exactly fit so I'm a bit at a loss.
